# Convexity of argmax

Tags: optimization

Suppose that the function $F(x,y)$ is supermodular in $(x,y)$. We know that this implies that $x^* =\operatorname{arg\, max} F(x,y)$ is increasing in $y$. Under which conditions (if any) do we have that $x^*$ is a convex function of $y$?

Comment: Interesting question. Is there a particular class of $F$ of interest? I have thought about this before but did not get anywhere at this high level of generality.

Comment: Only thing we have is that F is concave in x. Did you get any results for a particular class of F? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This may no longer be relevant but since the question is still open, here goes.

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and let $x^*(y)=\operatorname{arg\, max}_{x\in X}F(x, y)$. Suppose that $x^*(y)$ is a singleton (i.e., unique maximizer) and $x^*(y)<\sup X$ for all $y\in Y$.

The paper linked below shows that if $\partial F(x, y)/\partial x$ is a quasi-convex, then $x^*(y)$ is a convex function. The paper actually provides a more general result that allows for non-unique maximizers, multidimensional choice variables, and does not require differentiability. There are also no assumptions such as supermodularity imposed on $F$, which means that if you additionally assume supermodularity of $F$ along with quasi-convexity of $\partial F/\partial x$, then your $x^*(y)$ should be convex and increasing in $y$.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/26543895